# sizeof in c program output

Tags: c, char, sizeof

**Problem Statement:-**

What would be the output for the following program?

```
main( ) 
{ 
 printf ( "\n%d%d", sizeof ( '3' ), sizeof ( "3" ), sizeof ( 3 ) ) ; 
}
```

I am working with 32 bit gcc compiler. And it is printing the output as-

```
4, 2, 4
```

I am confused why it is printing `4` for `sizeof ( '3' )`. 3 is in single inverted commas so it will be a character right? Then it shouldn't print out 4? Am I right?

Comment: -1. There are only two `%d`'s and no commas in that `printf` string, so that is not the output. Please don't paraphrase results.

Comment: You are missing one `%d` in `printf` it  should be `printf("%d%d%d",...)`

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I think by "single inverted comma", the OP means "apostrophe" or "single quote". Something tells me english isn't his/her first language.

Comment: @CarlNorum No, I mean in the format string. Look carefully at the program and look at the output.

Comment: Oh gotcha.  Yeah, the "smart quotes" on the character literal are another giveaway.

Comment: I fixed the sloppy quotes for single quotes...but I'm not fixing what should be three occurrences of `%zu` with commas and spaces separating them.

Comment: Note that in C++, `sizeof('3')` would be 1, not 4.  And if you had a machine with 16-bit `int`, it would 2, not 4, in C (but still 1 in C++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character literals are integers in C.  That means `sizeof('3')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.  On your machine, that looks like `4`.

Editorial notes:

1. Don't use `%d` as the format string when printing `sizeof` results.  `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` instead.
2. You should use a correct prototype for `main`.  That is: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  Not just `main()`.
3. If you use the correct prototype for `main`, make sure your program returns something.  `return 0;` at the end, for example.

Comment: whats this "3" considered? why size 2 ?

Comment: `"3"` is a string literal.  It contains two characters - a `'3'` and a terminating `'\0'` (null) character.

Comment: even null 'll be added for sizeof ("\0") [it gives 2]?

Comment: Yes, that's a string literal that contains two `'\0'` characters.  A string literal isn't necessarily a string, as you've found.

Comment: how sizeof works? (calculates size  [here it includes "\0"]) [sizeof computes results at compile time] but i don't get it.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  `sizeof` can compute results at runtime, too (for VLAs, for example).